# How to Vector3.normalized only if exceeding -1/1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am currently creating movement for a character and all is well except diagonal movement is doubled because it is obviously combining vertical and horizontal movement. Now I did try normalizing the Vector3, but that results in a delayed stop for the character. According to other forums I read, I think it's because it should only normalize when it is greater/less than -1/1 but I don't know how to setup this constraint. Please help!

```
forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, forwardInput).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate(movement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem with always normalizing is that you move with the same speed no matter how far the input is pressed.

This is no problem on a PC with keyboard input which is either `0`, `-1` or `1` but will not work as expected if e.g. using a controller since it will also round up the value in case you normalize if the original input vector's magnitude is smaller then `1`.

So yes you should normalize only in case the magnitude of the input vector exceeds `1` e.g. when pressing in two directions at the same time in order to maintain a certain maximum speed. In order to not type redundant code I would rather separate the vector and assignment in different variables and use [`Vector3.Normalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Normalize.html) instead:

```
forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

var inputVector = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, forwardInput);

// note that a magnitude is always positive, there is no -1
// if magnitude > 1 then implicitely also sqrMagnitude > 1 and the other way round
// sqrMagnitude is faster to access then magnitude and for this check
// here provides the same result 
if(inputVector.sqrMagnitude > 1) inputVector.Normalize();

var movement = inputVector * speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate(movement);
```

Comment: Also moving with transform.Translate is a little "nooby", better with rigidbody.velocity = movement, if know how to deal with jump :P

Comment: @Windgate I don't see a `Rigidbody` involved in the question, though ;) Using an entire physics system to just get movement to work is more "nooby" then sticking to the relevant tools in my opinion ;) Totally depends on the project

Comment: Just trying to invit @FloodAndBones to explore more types of controllers, transform.Translate is the first approach to a controller, and I think he is starting with Unity

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance! Yes I am working with Unity and have a limited knowledge as I have just started out. I am familiar with Rigidbodies though and have worked with using AddForce as a movement method. But I am completely new to the whole velocity thing so that's what I am currently figuring out! But thank you so much for the help!